# MPI C++ - Rank changes

Tags: c++, mpi

I have paralleled my code and a part of it has a strange behavior that I can't figure out. The piece of code is as follow:

```
int SizeEdgeForNewNodes_int;

{ 
    MPI_Request send_request[mpi_size - 1], recv_request;
    MPI_Status send_status[mpi_size - 1], recv_status;
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (myrank == 0) {
        for (int m = 1; m < mpi_size; ++m){
            int sendTag = m;
            MPI_Isend(&SizeEdgeForNewNodes[m], 1, MPI_INT64_T, m, sendTag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request[m - 1]);
            cout << myrank << " - SizeEdgeForNewNodes[m] = " << SizeEdgeForNewNodes[m] << endl;
        }
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

    if (myrank > 0) {
        int recvTag = myrank;
        cout << "within b4 - myrank = " << myrank << endl;
        MPI_Irecv(&SizeEdgeForNewNodes_int, 1, MPI_INT64_T, 0, recvTag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_request); // 1st non blocking receive
        cout << "within after - myrank = " << myrank << endl;
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

    if (myrank != 0){
        MPI_Wait(&recv_request, &recv_status);
    }       
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

    if (myrank == 0){
        MPI_Waitall(mpi_size - 1, send_request, send_status);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
}
```

When running the code in Debug version everything is fine and the obtained output is:

```
0 - SizeEdgeForNewNodes[m] = 0
within b4 - myrank = 1
within after - myrank = 1
```

When running in Release, I obtain the following output:

```
0 - SizeEdgeForNewNodes[m] = 0
within b4 - myrank = 1
within after - myrank = 0
```

I am using intel-15.0 compiler and the MPI implementation is mvapich2/2.1.
Thank you for your help,

JB

Comment: Seems quite likely that you are writing beyond the bounds of allocated memory.

Comment: What does that mean? Which direction should I investigate to solve this? thx

Comment: It's not my job to assess the quality of your code, but how about you replace all those lines shown with a single `MPI_Scatter` call?

Comment: @JbGT Something like what Ali Mirzaei says below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive a 64 bit int but your buffer is allocated 32 bit! So the received value would over write on your local variable (myrank).
To solve this issue change the dataType of the receive buffer(SizeEdgeForNewNodes_int)